# Migrating Apache Felix SCR to OSGI Declarative Services

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-felix, declarative-services, metatype

I'm Migrating from Apache Felix SCR Annotations to OSGI Declarative Services and here is my Problem.

Before I had: SCR annotation Implementation

```
@Component (ds = true, immediate = true, metatype = false, policy = ConfigurationPolicy.OPTIONAL)
@Service (SampleService.class)
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService
{
 ..
 ..
}
```

Now I have : DS annotation Implementation

```
@Component (configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.OPTIONAL, immediate = true, service = SampleService.class)
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService
{
 ..
 ..
}
```

In DS annotation Implementation How i have to map **ds** and **metatype** params?

Else it is fine to ignore ds and metatype params?

Comment: Do you use Maven plugin to process those annotations? What maven plugin do you use, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ds=true as well as metatype=false are the defaults anyway. You can safely ignore them in your case.

Comment: Thanks @Christian Schneider. Similarly how can map **specVersion ** in DS annotation Implementation?

Comment: Specversion in DS is partly defined by the spec you use as maven dependency and partly by the features you use. Simply leave this attribute out in DS.